# Write the min-max model in the standard LP form

Tags: linear-programming

I was given two linear systems {$2x=1$, $x=1$} and I was told to write the min-max model. Which I hope I did correctly and got

$|| Ax-b||$ = max {$||2x-1||, ||x-1||$} -> min.

now it is asking me to write the min-max model in the standard LP form as defined on-page $152$ of [Forst]

[image]

So I am assuming that the form is (P).

I have found [these lecture notes online](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/sloan-school-of-management/15-053-optimization-methods-in-management-science-spring-2013/tutorials/MIT15_053S13_tut06.pdf) which helped me understand how to change LP into SF. However, I am still unsure of how I can do that with my question. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: This linear system is empty $x=1$ do not satisfy $2x=1$. You can use the $||.||_{\infty}$ to minimize the error but, there is no solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, you want to minimize the error of $||Ax-b||_{\infty}$. Let $t=\max\{|2x-1|, |x-1|\}$ the error of the linear system solution.

$$
\begin{align}
\min ~ t & \\ 
&|2x-1|\leq t\\
&|x-1|\leq t\\
& t\geq 0 , ~ x\in \mathbb{R}
\end{align}
$$

Removing the module

$$
\begin{align}
\min ~ t & \\ 
& 2x-1\leq t\\
& 2x-1\geq t\\
& x-1\leq t\\
& x-1\geq t\\
& t\geq 0 , ~ x\in \mathbb{R}
\end{align}
$$

Putting in standard form using $x=x_1 - x_2$ and adding $s_1, ...s_4$

$$
\begin{align}
\min ~ t & \\ 
& 2x_1 - 2x_2 -t +s_1 = 1\\
& 2x_1 - 2x_2 -t -s_2 = 1\\
& x_1 - x_2 -t +s_3 = 1\\
& x_1 - x_2-t - s_4 = 1\\
& t\geq 0 ,  x_i\geq 0, s_j\geq 0
\end{align}
$$